Efficiently compute volume of hexahedral Voronoi cell
Consider following points in $\mathbb R^3$:
$0 = (0,0,0)$, $p_1 = (1.1,0,0)$, $p_2 = (-1.1, 0,0.01)$, $p_3 = (0,1.2,0)$, $p_4 = (0,-1.2,0.05)$, $p_5 = (0.005,0,1.5)$, $p_6 = (0.05,0.06,-1.1)$.
Now consider all the points that are closer to $0$ than they are to any of the points $p_i$. This forms a Voronoi cell in the form of a (irregular) hexahedron:
$$C = \lbrace x \in \mathbb R^3 \mid \Vert x - 0 \Vert  \leq \min_{i} \Vert x - p_i \Vert \rbrace$$
The vectors $p_i$ are normals of the corresponding faces, and the faces have a  distance of $\frac12 \Vert p_i \Vert$, to the origin.
Note that the coordinates I have chosen here are arbitrary. If you round them to the nearest integer, $C$ will be a cube, centered at $0$, oriented along the coordinate axes, and with side length $1$. I just chose weird coordinates to stress that I want to solve a more general case.
The volume of $C$ (i.e. $V = \int_{C} 1 dx$) can be computed by e.g. by computing the vertex coordinates by intersecting the three corresponding planes and then decomposing the hexahedron into pyramids, and adding up their volumes. While this works, it is quite a tedious computation and not very elegant. Alternatively we could also define the bijection (i.e. trilinear map) from the unit cube to $C$ and compute the volume via the integral change of variables formula, but we'd again need the vertices.
Question: I was now wondering, is there a more elegant way? Can we somehow directly use the $p_i$ without having to compute the vertices?
An unfinished I approach I was thinking about was decomposing the hexahedron into pyramids, formed by the faces and $0$. Here, $\frac12 \Vert p_i \Vert$ is the height. If we knew the area of the faces, we could therefore easily compute the volumes. But we'd need to know these areas. Is there maybe some theorem from spherical geometry that would help us with that?

Connected : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19661317/5802041
